# R conditional filter

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes in R.

Release dataframe

```
Date     Product
2011-01-13   A  
2011-02-15   A  
2011-01-14   B  
2011-02-15   B
```

Casedata dataframe

```
Date       Product Numberofcases 
2011-01-13 A       50
2011-01-12 A       20
2011-01-11 A       100
2011-01-10 A       120
2011-01-09 A       150
2011-01-08 A       180
2011-01-07 A       200
2011-01-06 A       220
2011-01-23 A       500
2011-01-31 A       450
2011-02-08 A       50
2011-02-09 A       1000
2011-02-10 A       1200
2011-02-11 A       1500
2011-02-12 A       1800
2011-02-13 A       2000
2011-02-14 A       2200
2011-02-15 A       5000
2011-01-31 A       4500
:::
:::
2011-01-15 B       1000
```

My requirement is for every product release date(from release dataframe), I should obtain the corresponding sum(numberofcases) one week prior to the release date(in the casedata dataframe). ie., for product A and release date 2011-01-13, it should be sum of all cases in the previous week (from 2011-01-06 to 2011-01-13) ie., (50+20+100+120+150+180+200+220)

```
Releasedate Product Numberofcasesoneweekpriorrelease
2011-01-13  A       1040
2011-02-15  A       19250
2011-01-14  B       ...
2011-02-15  B       ...
```

What I have tried :

```
beforerelease <- sqldf("select product,release.date_release,sum(numberofcasescreated) as numberofcasesbeforerelease from release left join casedata using (product) where date_case>=weekbeforerelease and date_case<=date_release group by product,date_release") 
finaldf <- merge(beforerelease,afterelease,by=c("monthyear","product"))
```

I am struck and it is not giving me the expected outcome. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: You provided some code, thank you. Can you provide a small sample dataset? (I recommend with something easily copy/paste-able, either source building random data or the output from `dput` on a small dataset.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `data.table` package you could follow two approaches:

**1)** Using the `foverlaps` functionality:

```
library(data.table)
# convert to a 'data.table' with 'setDT()'
# and create a release window
setDT(release)[, `:=` (bdat = as.Date(Date)-7, edat = as.Date(Date))][, Date := NULL]
# convert to a 'data.table' and create a 2nd date column for use with 'foverlaps
setDT(casedata)[, `:=` (bdat = as.Date(Date), edat = as.Date(Date))][, Date := NULL]

# set the key for use in 'foverlaps'
setkey(release, Product, bdat, edat)
setkey(casedata, Product, bdat, edat)

# do an overlap join ('foverlaps') and summarise
foverlaps(casedata, release, type = 'within', nomatch = 0L)[, .(cases.prior.release = sum(Numberofcases)), by = .(Product, release.date = edat)]
```

which gives:

```
   Product release.date cases.prior.release
1:       A   2011-01-13                1040
2:       A   2011-02-15               14750
```

**2)** Using the standard join functionality of `data.table`:

```
setDT(release)
setDT(casedata)

casedata[, Date := as.Date(Date)
         ][release[, `:=` (Date = as.Date(Date), idx = .I)
                   ][, .(dates = seq(Date-7,Date,'day')), by = .(Product,idx)], 
           on = c('Product', Date = 'dates'), nomatch = 0L
           ][, .(releasedate = Date[.N], cases.prior.release = sum(Numberofcases)), by = .(Product,idx)
             ][, idx := NULL]
```

which will get you the same result.

---

Used data:

```
release <- structure(list(Date = c("2011-01-13", "2011-02-15", "2011-01-14", "2011-02-15"), 
                          Product = c("A", "A", "B", "B")), 
                     .Names = c("Date", "Product"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

casedata <- structure(list(Date = c("2011-01-13", "2011-01-12", "2011-01-11", "2011-01-10", "2011-01-09", "2011-01-08", "2011-01-07", "2011-01-06", "2011-01-23", "2011-01-31", "2011-02-08", "2011-02-09", "2011-02-10", "2011-02-11", "2011-02-12", "2011-02-13", "2011-02-14", "2011-02-15", "2011-01-31"), 
                           Product = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
                           Numberofcases = c(50L, 20L, 100L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 200L, 220L, 500L, 450L, 50L, 1000L, 1200L, 1500L, 1800L, 2000L, 2200L, 5000L, 4500L)), 
                      .Names = c("Date", "Product", "Numberofcases"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the recently implemented `non-equi` joins feature in the [current development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table, v1.9.7`, this can be done simply as (assuming all Date columns are of class `Date`):

```
require(data.table)
setDT(release)[, Date2 := Date-7L]
setDT(casedata)[release, on = .(Product, Date >= Date2, Date <= Date), 
                .(count = sum(Numberofcases)), by = .EACHI]

#    Product       Date       Date count
# 1:       A 2011-01-06 2011-01-13  1040
# 2:       A 2011-02-08 2011-02-15 14750
# 3:       B 2011-01-07 2011-01-14    NA
# 4:       B 2011-02-08 2011-02-15    NA
```

Comment: Nice! I guess i missed the introduction of the *non-equi* joins.

Comment: What does the `by = .EACHI` do in this case? Is it equivalent to `allow.cartesian`? Also, is there any way for arithmetic operations like `Date-7L` to be performed on the fly inside the `on=.(...)` argument? This would be [especially helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658775/data-table-non-equi-join-with-arithmetic-operations) for xxl sized datasets.