# Data.Table non-equi join with arithmetic operations

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to do a complex self-join on a (for R) large data structure (tens to hundreds of millions of rows), so creating new columns just for this one operation is something I'd like to avoid as it would literally add gigs of memory pressure to my object, especially since I want to play with different join time parameters.

Structure of `dt_sample`:

```
str(dt_sample)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  50 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ gateway_airport: chr  "BOS" "BOS" "BOS" "BOS" ...
 $ final_airport  : chr  "ORD" "BNA" "ORD" "RSW" ...
 $ dept_utc       : POSIXct, format: "2016-11-17 15:09:00" "2016-11-17 21:00:00" "2016-11-17 12:40:00" ...
 $ arriv_utc      : POSIXct, format: "2016-11-17 17:03:00" "2016-11-17 23:00:00" "2016-11-17 14:35:00" ...
 $ airlines_id    : chr  "UA" "B6" "UA" "B6" ...
 $ flight_number  : num  1472 1907 449 965 3839 ...
```

The idea is to do a self-join on where X's final_airport is Y's gateway_airport, and Y's dept_utc is within a range of X's arriv_UTC (in my example below between +30 minutes and +8 hours inclusive).

This works, but creates a large structure that gets filtered after the merge:

```
result <- merge(dt_sample, dt_sample, by.x=c("final_airport"),
                by.y=("gateway_airport"))[arriv_utc.x + 1800 <= dept_utc.y 
                                          &arriv_utc.x  +28800 >= dept_utc.y,]
```

I'd prefer to use the `on = .()` notation, but it does not seem to allow arithmetic operations on the join elements and the self-join seems to confuse it as well. Again, I'd prefer not to add new columns. **Any ideas on how to use data.table effectively here?**

The result of head(result) is a data.table with 3 airports per row, with the origin, intermediary stop and final airport (+ some extra info). The full result for the sample in the dput below is 19 rows long.

```
   final_airport gateway_airport          dept_utc.x         arriv_utc.x airlines_id.x flight_number.x final_airport          dept_utc.y         arriv_utc.y
1:           IAD             BOS 2016-11-17 14:35:00 2016-11-17 16:18:00            UA             525           JAX 2016-11-17 17:30:00 2016-11-17 19:37:00
2:           IAD             BOS 2016-11-17 14:35:00 2016-11-17 16:18:00            UA             525           SAV 2016-11-17 17:30:00 2016-11-17 19:16:00
3:           IAD             BOS 2016-11-17 14:35:00 2016-11-17 16:18:00            UA             525           TYS 2016-11-17 17:31:00 2016-11-17 19:10:00
4:           IAD             BOS 2016-11-17 14:35:00 2016-11-17 16:18:00            UA             525           DEN 2016-11-17 17:35:00 2016-11-17 19:36:00
5:           IAD             BOS 2016-11-17 14:35:00 2016-11-17 16:18:00            UA             525           GSO 2016-11-17 17:40:00 2016-11-17 19:09:00
6:           IAD             BOS 2016-11-17 14:35:00 2016-11-17 16:18:00            UA             525           LAX 2016-11-17 17:40:00 2016-11-17 20:25:00
   airlines_id.y flight_number.y
1:            AC            3891
2:            AC            2736
3:            AC            2567
4:            UA             735
5:            AC            2727
6:            UA             632
```

**Click below to expand 50-row sample dput structure for reproducibility:**

```html
structure(list(gateway_airport = c("BOS", "BOS", "BOS", "BOS", 
"IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "BOS", "IAD", "BOS", "BOS", "BOS", "BOS", 
"IAD", "BOS", "BOS", "IAD", "BOS", "BOS", "BOS", "IAD", "BOS", 
"BOS", "BOS", "BOS", "IAD", "BOS", "IAD", "BOS", "IAD", "IAD", 
"IAD", "BOS", "IAD", "BOS", "BOS", "BOS", "IAD", "IAD", "BOS", 
"IAD", "BOS", "BOS", "BOS", "IAD", "BOS", "IAD", "BOS", "BOS", 
"IAD"), final_airport = c("ORD", "BNA", "ORD", "RSW", "ORF", 
"MCO", "DEN", "CLT", "DFW", "PHL", "ORD", "MIA", "ORD", "GSO", 
"JFK", "FLL", "ORD", "ORD", "LGA", "LGA", "LAX", "ORD", "IAD", 
"RIC", "DEN", "TYS", "SEA", "TPA", "SAV", "ROA", "SEA", "DFW", 
"PHL", "MIA", "IAH", "PHL", "LGA", "JFK", "JAX", "TPA", "TPA", 
"IAH", "DFW", "LAS", "SAV", "IAD", "LAX", "LGA", "SFO", "LAX"
), dept_utc = structure(c(1479395340, 1479416400, 1479386400, 
1479397800, 1479420600, 1479422700, 1479404100, 1479386100, 1479384840, 
1479387600, 1479378840, 1479386700, 1479402000, 1479404400, 1479403800, 
1479418500, 1479421500, 1479384000, 1479420900, 1479387600, 1479404400, 
1479412500, 1479411000, 1479381000, 1479412920, 1479403860, 1479395700, 
1479389100, 1479398400, 1479421500, 1479415200, 1479400140, 1479415440, 
1479380400, 1479406080, 1479382200, 1479413700, 1479394800, 1479403800, 
1479414300, 1479423000, 1479392520, 1479411600, 1479384000, 1479403800, 
1479393300, 1479391200, 1479400200, 1479397500, 1479420600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), arriv_utc = structure(c(1479402180, 1479423600, 
1479393300, 1479410880, 1479424620, 1479431160, 1479411360, 1479395520, 
1479393900, 1479393360, 1479386700, 1479400020, 1479408780, 1479409740, 
1479408240, 1479431340, 1479425280, 1479391860, 1479425640, 1479392100, 
1479414300, 1479419280, 1479417120, 1479387600, 1479422940, 1479409800, 
1479407460, 1479397800, 1479408180, 1479426180, 1479425580, 1479409500, 
1479421740, 1479390420, 1479418260, 1479387900, 1479418320, 1479399360, 
1479411420, 1479426420, 1479431940, 1479404880, 1479423900, 1479395340, 
1479410160, 1479399480, 1479401580, 1479404640, 1479411300, 1479430860
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), airlines_id = c("UA", 
"B6", "UA", "B6", "AC", "UA", "UA", "AA", "AA", "B6", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AC", "EI", "B6", "UA", "AA", "B6", "AA", "UA", "UA", "UA", 
"B6", "UA", "AC", "B6", "UA", "B6", "AC", "UA", "AA", "B6", "AA", 
"UA", "AA", "B6", "B6", "AC", "EI", "UA", "UA", "B6", "B6", "AC", 
"UA", "UA", "B6", "UA", "UA"), flight_number = c(1472, 1907, 
449, 965, 3839, 419, 735, 1735, 2569, 459, 1155, 1274, 1240, 
2727, 5021, 1969, 511, 1404, 1331, 2126, 632, 981, 511, 1481, 
448, 2567, 597, 2002, 49, 2726, 357, 1556, 1059, 1083, 1233, 
543, 1231, 1308, 3891, 5290, 360, 167, 1115, 1077, 2736, 525, 
470, 831, 477, 325)), .Names = c("gateway_airport", "final_airport", 
"dept_utc", "arriv_utc", "airlines_id", "flight_number"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2301358>)
```

Comment: So, you want to do a non-equi join as [implemented](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1452) in the development version?

Comment: @Roland, yes but with something like `arriv_utc + 1800 > dept_utc` in the non-equi join

Comment: It's trivial and efficient to create `arriv_utc_plus := arriv_utc + 1800`.

Comment: Trivial for 50 rows yes, but as I said, I'm talking a very large data structure, I'd prefer not to create new columns. Arithmetic joins are acceptable in SQL, I'm wondering if there's a data.table option

Comment: Are you saying you deal with a data.table that is not over-allocated?

Comment: What does `truelength(DT)` tell you? If this is more than the number of columns the memory for your data.table is over-allocated and adding a column won't need additional RAM (that's one of data.table's features). Anyway, arithmetic joins are planed, but [not implemented yet](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128367/discussion-between-serban-tanasa-and-roland).

Comment: This is [FR #1639](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639).

Answer (score 3):

As already explained in the comments, you can use non-equi join functionality to perform this kind of join.
Because on the fly calculation in `on` argument is [not yet supported](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639) you have to create those two columns before performing join. The good thing is that it doesn't cost any extra memory and is extremely fast.

```r
setDT(dt_sample)

## OP: join, then subset
result <- merge(dt_sample, dt_sample, by.x=c("final_airport"),
                by.y=("gateway_airport"))[arriv_utc.x + 1800 <= dept_utc.y 
                                          &arriv_utc.x  +28800 >= dept_utc.y,]

## efficient: non-equi join
d = copy(dt_sample)
d[, `:=`(arriv_utc2=arriv_utc+1800, arriv_utc3=arriv_utc+28800)]
d[d, nomatch=NULL, on=.(
  final_airport == gateway_airport,
  arriv_utc2 <= dept_utc,
  arriv_utc3 >= dept_utc
  ), j=.(
    x.final_airport, x.gateway_airport, x.dept_utc, x.arriv_utc, x.airlines_id, x.flight_number, i.final_airport, i.dept_utc, i.arriv_utc, i.airlines_id, i.flight_number
  )] -> ans
setnames(result, names(ans))
all.equal(ans, result, check.attributes=FALSE, ignore.row.order=TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
```